# Accessing Singleton object second times caused app to crash

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a a singleton class here is the code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CustomColor.h"


@interface Properties : NSObject {
    UIColor *bgColor;
    CustomColor *bggColor;
}
@property(retain) UIColor *bgColor;
@property (retain) CustomColor *bggColor;

+ (id)sharedProperties;
@end

#import "Properties.h"

static Properties *sharedMyProperties = nil;

@implementation Properties

@synthesize bgColor;
@synthesize bggColor;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedProperties
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
            if(sharedMyProperties == nil)
            [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyProperties;
}
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
            if(sharedMyProperties == nil)
            {
                sharedMyProperties = [super allocWithZone:zone];
                return sharedMyProperties;
            }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  return self;
}
- (id)retain {
    return self;
}
- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX; //denotes an object that cannot be released
}
- (void)release {
    // never release
}
- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

        FSColor *bc = [[FSColor alloc] init];
        bc.red = bc.green = bc.blue = bc.hue = bc.sat = bc.bri = 0;
        bggColor = bc;

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
    [bgColor release];
    [bggColor release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I have a UIView' subclass. in which i am using it. I am calling drawRect method after each second. It only run once and then app crashes.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    Properties *sharedProprties = [Properties sharedProperties];
    …...
    ….
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[sharedProprties bgColor] CGColor]);
    …..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you do `self.bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:...]`?

Without the `self.` I think you may be accessing the `ivar` directly, and therefore assigning it an autoreleased object which won't live very long (rather than using the synthesized property setter, which would retain it). I could be wrong about this, I'm stuck targeting older Mac OS X systems so I haven't been able to play much with Objective-C 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your static sharedProperties gets never assigned. It is missing in the init method or in the sharedProperties static method.

Here's a sample pattern for [singletons](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern) (last post)

Also accessing properties without self. may cause bad access errors too.

Regards

Comment: It is assigned inside `+allocWithZone:`

Comment: Yes, but as far as i know the assignment is done in the allocWithZone method, the instance could be stored on a different memory location (different memory zone) as the variables do which can cause access errors. So I would assign the sharedInstance in the init method instead of allocWithZone

Comment: The space for an instance's ivars is allocated wherever the instance is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but note that a simple call to `[Properties alloc]` will mean it's no longer a singleton!

```
+ (id)sharedProperties
{
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if(sharedMyProperties == nil)
    {
      sharedMyProperties = [[self alloc] init];
    }
  }
  return sharedMyProperties;
}
```